# What does <T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor:T) mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Every typescript decorator need to define this?What does this mean?Why not set this default in typescript language or developer need to write this every time.

```
function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A decorator needs as a parameter an object including a constructor. This object can instantiate different classes, that is why you have to use a generic function. That is why you need a function which looks like this `function classDecorator<T>(constructor:T) {}` 
Where the T is replacing by a class or a type. for example, you can call the function like this: `classDecorator<MyClass>(myClass)`
(See more about Generics here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

In order to restrict the type classes that classDecorator can use, you specify it after the extends: `extends {new(...args:any[]):{}`. You are basically saying that your class need a constructor in its definition through this (`new`...).

Upon my knowledge, it is not set as default template simply because the decorator pattern is not specifically defined in typescript definition as well as many other existing patterns.